# Setting the date format in JXTable cell

Tags: java, datepicker, swingx, tablecelleditor, jxtable

On [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11822526/how-to-add-a-jxdatepicker-for-a-jtable-column/11822655#11822655) I've figured out how to add a JXDatePicker in to a JXTable (or JTable) cell. But I've a small issue now.

DatePicker pops up and works fine according to my need. But I can't change the display format of the date in the cell. It shows in the following long format.

```
Eg: Wed Aug 01 00:00:00 IST 2012
```

But I need it in `dd-MMM-yyyy` format.

I've tried changing the `DatePickerCellEditor`'s format. It partly works. Which means, now it shows the date according to the set format when that cell is in focus. But when I focus on some other cell, it again goes back to the above format.

May be the fault is not with the `DatePickerCellEditor`, may be it has to do something with the `tableModel`. But can't figure it out. Any help is appreciated..

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per you're previous question, the process it pretty much the same, except you want to use renderer instead of an editor

```
public class DateCellRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {

    @Override
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable jtable, Object value, boolean selected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {

        if (value instanceof Date) {

            // You could use SimpleDateFormatter instead
            value = DateFormat.getDateInstance().format(value);

        }


        return super.getTableCellRendererComponent(jtable, value, selected, hasFocus, row, column);

    }
```

Then, to apply the render you can either apply it to specific column (so only that column will use it), or in the case of something like `Date` you might want to use it for all columns using the `Date` value...

```
JTable table = new JTable();

DateCellRenderer renderer = new DateCellRenderer();
// Apply for a single column
table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setCellRenderer(renderer);
// OR apply for all columns using the Date class
table.setDefaultRenderer(Date.class, renderer);
```

Comment: @Anubis All roads lead to Rome ;)

Comment: Thank you @MadProgrammer. In my previous thread [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11822526/how-to-add-a-jxdatepicker-for-a-jtable-column/11822659#comment15719785_11822659], `kleopatra` has given me the same answer, but his way of implementing the `TableCellRenderer` is much simple. Thanks goes to him too..

Answer (score 1):

That is because a TableCellEditor is only used, when you really are editing a cells value. For representing a value, while not in edit-mode a TableCellRenderer is used.

I recommend reading this [article](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender) to understand more about the concept of renderer and editors for tablecells.