# DatePickerCellEditor format changing when selected

Tags: java, swing, awt

I have created JTable having **DatePickerCellEditor** with DateFormat(**dd/MM/yyyy**).

[image: DatePickerCell]

The DateFormat is changing when date is selected.
like this :

[image: DateFormatChanged]

here's my code :

```
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
final DatePickerCellEditor dateCellPrev = new DatePickerCellEditor(formatter);
dateCellPrev.addCellEditorListener(new CellEditorListener() {
    @Override
    public void editingStopped(ChangeEvent arg0) {
        dateCellPrev.setFormats(formatter);
    }
    @Override
    public void editingCanceled(ChangeEvent arg0) {
        dateCellPrev.setFormats(formatter);
    }
});
table.getColumnModel().getColumn(19).setCellEditor(dateCellPrev);
```

I want to change format to "dd/MM/yyyy" not like format in last picture

Comment: You've forgot to post a question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Setting the date format in JXTable cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11823334/setting-the-date-format-in-jxtable-cell)

Comment: I tried solution for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11823334/setting-the-date-format-in-jxtable-cell, and it didn't work

Comment: @mohamed.bc please provide a [mcve] so we can provide a solution that is suitable for your case. As I see, you've installed an editor, but no renderer. You need to set it. Something like `table.getColumnModel().getColumn(19).setCellRenderer(new DateCellRenderer());` Where `DateCellRenderer` is the renderer from the post you've referenced in your last comment.

Comment: Ok no problème.

Comment: Any other solutions ??